# I want my activity to start a new activity in a dialog with transparency?

Tags: android

I have an Activity with some buttons,if I click a specific button a new Activity is started which show some images,I want this activity to be opened in a dialog showing the images, select one image and return the image path to the first activity? I have the code for selection of image but how to send image path  back to the first acivity? Plz help

Comment: Check Shailendra's answer and please post the code that you have used for displaying images in dialog. So that we can suggest you for the returned URL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**set activity theme** as `android:Theme.Dialog` in menifest .

**For 2nd doubt: Thats to get Image Path:**

frist start second activity by `StartActivityForResult()` . Now put path into intent by `putExtra(key, value)` and `finish()` . Now execution will come back to **`OnActivityResult`** of Activity 1 . Read your path by `GetExtra(key)`.

Read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: +1 agree, this is the answer for opening a new activity in a dialog.

Comment: +1, for activity theme, If possible give him more info about return image path from that dialog activity.

Comment: frist start second activity by StartActivityForResult() . now put path into intent by putExtra(key)and finish . now execution will come back to OnActivityResult of ativity1 . read your path by GetExtra(key).   read more about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: @ShailendraRajawat i have updated answer for the detail you have mentioned. Give/update the answer same way.

Answer (score 2):

Activity1 :

Call Activity2 like so:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_SELECTION_RESULT);
```

.

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) 
    {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == Activit1.IMAGE_SELECTION_RESULT) 
      {                    
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
          {
             Bundle bun = data.getExtras();
             String file = bun.getString(KEY_FILENAME);

          }
      } 
   }
```

---

Activity2

When you select the file

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.putExtra(Activity1.KEY_FILENAME, getPath());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

---

As for the transparent bit add this to your manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" android:theme="@style/Transparent" />
```

or `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` or `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog` as per your satisfaction.

And in the `onCreate()` of Activity2 :

```
    getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, 
                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND );
```

Answer (score 0):

Store image path in a static variable and get the path from variable. Note the class instance not create  and direct use variable like  Config.path  Config is class and path is static variable